# using angular js collapse function on panels html 5.0

Tags: html, angularjs

Basically Currently I have html code which builds a layout of panels and I want to basically expand and collapse these panels , for some reason when i load the assets and run my app , the panels appear collapsed but does not expand when i click the panel title the code is below , i am using angular js with html5 . if someone can help quick i would appreciate that.

```
<div class="row clearfix" >
    <div ng-repeat="i in ctrl.coreControlpanelItems" class="col-md-12 column" >
        <div ng-class="{'panel-primary': hover}" ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false"  class="panel panel-default animated fadeInUp">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <i class="pull-left {{i.icon}}"/>
                <h5 class="panel-title">
                    <a href="#" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">
                    <a ui-sref="{{i.ref}}">{{i.group}}</a>
                    </a>        
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="collapsed">
                <div class="panel-body ">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="s in i.items"><a ui-sref="{{s.ref}}">{{s.name}}<a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have nested `a` tags in your `panel-title` element. That's a no-no.

Second, you're can't put `ng-model` on an `a` tag.

Third, your `panel-title` is supposed to expand something but you also have a link inside of it which if clicked on would negate what you're trying to do with the expanding...

Comment: could you guide me how to? im new to html and i tried an internet example on how to do the collapsing , at the moment the panel is collapsing but the onclick on the panel title isnt working

Comment: It's not working because there's no text inside of the element with the ng-click. Move the ng-click onto the h5.panel-title element and then put whatever text you need inside of that element.

Comment: worked but isnt showing my panel-title , when i expand the panel-title disapears

Comment: worked thanks basically i just took out the ng-show and everything is great now